# Semantic-Ui Dropdown adjust width and align center

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

i can't adjust the width and align center the dropdown box
here is the code : [my code on fiddle to check](http://jsfiddle.net/efp8z6Ln/590/)
i use semantic ui fluid dropdown

```
<div id="123">
<div class="ui fluid selection dropdown ">
<input id="dpdown" type="hidden" name="user">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text">Select Friend</div>
<div class="menu">
<div class="item" data-value="jenny">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" src="/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg"> 
 Jenny Hess
</div>
<div class="item" data-value="elliot">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" src="/images/avatar/small/elliot.jpg"> 
Elliot Fu
</div>
<div class="item" data-value="stevie">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" src="/images/avatar/small/stevie.jpg"> 
Stevie Feliciano
</div>
<div class="item" data-value="christian">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" 
src="/images/avatar/small/christian.jpg"> Christian
</div>
<div class="item" data-value="matt">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" src="/images/avatar/small/matt.jpg"> 
Matt
</div>
<div class="item" data-value="justen">
  <img class="ui mini avatar image" src="/images/avatar/small/justen.jpg"> 
Justen Kitsune
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heads up, it should be `width: 50px;` not `width=50px;` - also, could you add placeholder images (https://placeholder.com/) for the sake of demonstration? As it stands the relative filepaths you have specified for your images won't resolve. Also, include your styles here, in this question, and combine your html and css into a Code Snippet for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

IDs cannot start with a digit and it's `width: 50px;`.

```
#container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzstes0z/

Comment: thanks , add a border-radius , but when dropdown open , i does not apply on drop down , how could i add border-radius in dropdown? link:http://jsfiddle.net/gzstes0z/1/

Comment: You need to override the default border-radius. 
`.dropdown .menu {
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px !important;
}
`